# Modern IE languages which do not permit consonant cluster at the begining of syllables

Tags: phonology, list-of-languages, phonotactics

and also please guide me how to acquire such information from online linguistics resources (for example WALS.info).

Comment: I think [Persian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persian_phonology#Phonotactics) counts, unless you consider consonant + semivowel sequences to be clusters. EDIT: But you seem to be familiar with Persian already...

Comment: Yes Persian is one of them

Comment: The only WALS map that I think would be relevant is [Syllable Structure](http://wals.info/feature/12A#2/19.3/152.9) and it does not show any Indo-European languages with simple syllable structure.

Comment: As already mentioned, Persian does not allow it. Therefore, you will hear some familiar words prefixed with an e-, especially loans. Unfortunately, I am not aware of such resources online to write a full answer. Let me have a look at it first.

Comment: @sumelic. This is because they define "simple" too narrowly. Persian does in fact have only single consonants in initial position, but in medial position it allows up to three consonants in succession.

Comment: @fdb: Right; I'm not saying the map rules out the existence of other languages that would answer this question, I'm just saying the map is not useful for identifying an answer to this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern Persian is known for this, hence `Isfahan` from earlier `Spāhān`, and I assume some other related Iranian languages share this phonotactic constraint.

Western Romance languages have tendencies against initial `st-`, `sp-`, `sk-`, similar to Persian (and Turkish).  Thus they have typically inserted `e-` (and many even drop the `-s-` in writing or speech, see for example [the descendants of Latin `schola`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schola#Descendants)), Ladino, Walloon and Sardinian go both ways.  Some Eastern Romance dialects changed or change `s-` into `ʃ-` before some consonants, similar to High German.

We should make a distinction between tendencies and real constraints, for example modern borrowings into French do preserve the clusters in words like `psychologie`, `xylophone`, `sphère` and so on.  Likewise the English rules for loans are a bit looser, whereas Spanish is stricter, but like English it breaks with the written form even in prescriptive use.

Every language has some tendencies ie frequencies and it is hard to know all regional spoken variations, but Slavic, Baltic, Germanic, Armenian, Celtic, Albanian, Hellenic are mostly happy with consonant clusters (although Greek has no `ʃ` and thus no `t͡ʃ`, German has no `ʒ` and thus no `d͡ʒ` and so on, and of course German has `ʃt-` but no `st-` in native words).

So my sense is that simple binary categorisation is not possible, and the remaining candidates are other Indo-Iranian languages, or non-Romance creoles or mixed languages with strong influence from Western Romance.

One method to check initial patterns is to seek in the dictionary, for example [en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Scottish_Gaelic/s#st](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Index:Scottish_Gaelic/s#st), being sure to check the IPA pronunciation as languages like English and Spanish do not necessarily pronounce these even when written.